# How to define complex regular expressions once and reuse them in multiple routes

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

In my Symfony5.1 application, there are a lot of routes using regular expression like this one:

```php
    /**
     * @Route("/foo/{page<^[1-9][0-9]*$>}", name="foo", methods="GET")
     */
    public function list(int $page = 1): Response
    {
        // ...
    }
```

The [route documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#parameters-validation) said that it's possible to use container parameter:

> Route requirements (and route paths too) can include [container parameters](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#configuration-parameters), which is useful to define complex regular expressions once and reuse them in multiple routes.

I created a parameter in the `services.yaml` file:

```yaml
    parameters:
        page: '<^[1-9][0-9]*$>'
```

But how do I call the above parameter in my route annotation?

I tried without success:

- `@Route("/foo/{page<page>}", name="foo", methods="GET")`
- `@Route("/foo/{page}", name="foo", methods="GET", requirements=env:page)`
- `@Route("/foo/{page}", name="foo", methods="GET", requirements={"page"=page})`
- `@Route("/foo/{page}", name="foo", methods="GET", requirements={"page"=parameter:page})`
- `@Route("/dogs/{page<%env(page)%>}", name="dogs", methods="GET")`
- `@Route("/foo/{page}", name="foo", methods="GET", requirements={"page"=%env(page)%})`

The two last ones aren't returning a 404 error but: Using "%env(page)%" is not allowed in routing configuration.

How to call my parameter in the route annotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Controller:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/foo/{page<%page%>}", name="foo", methods="GET")
     */
    public function list(int $page = 1): Response
    {
        // ...
    }
```

parameters.yaml

```
parameters:
  page: '^[1-9][0-9]*$' # Without `<` and `>`
```